# Regex - How to capture all iterations of a repeating pattern?

Tags: c++, regex

Take a look at this [example](https://regex101.com/r/DO1hQx/3), I want to capture not just the last iteration (which is 5), but also 2, 3 and 4. It says here:

> A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations...

but I don't know how to do this. Since I need this in C++, I was looking for a way to get all iterations of capturing group using some regex functions in C++, but I always end up with same groups which the website finds.

Comment: How about `instruction \d((,\d)*)`? (IMHO, this is meant in the cited text.) Though, this leaves still the task to separate the inner matches...

Comment: Though I like reg. expressions in general, I'm not so enthusiastic about usage in C++. This language has enough power to write any parsers in "readable" code with any context dependency beyond what reg. ex. can do (though the code size will surely become a bit larger). ;-) (It's just an opinion.)

Comment: I love regexp, but I hate hardcoded regular expressions - IMO this bad practice. RE should be used as configuration option or as user input. IMO problem here is trying match everything at once instead do constitutive searches.

Comment: I also understood that is what the comment reffered to, but nothing changes, see https://regex101.com/r/DO1hQx/5

Comment: _but nothing changes_? Now, you get two groups:  `,2,3,4,5` and `,5`. Isn't it what you were looking for?

Comment: Actually, I made a regex to match .char(or .byte) directive in assembly, it looks like this ^.char\s*(-?\d+|".*"|'.'|\w+)(\s*,\s*(-?\d+|".*"|'.'|\w+))*$, and I need to catch all those arguments split by a comma, (although a comma might appear in one of arguments like "ad,c"). So, what do you guys suggest I should do?

Comment: @Scheff I want to extract 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 but each of them separately. The example catches only the last iteration (,5), I would like to catch (,2), (,3) and (,4) as well

Comment: How about [`std::regex_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_iterator)?

Comment: In such situations, I prefer pure C++ code: [Appetizer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50021308/7478597). An alternative could be something based on `lex` and `yacc` (or `flex` and `bison`). I must admit that `lex` uses reg. expressions as well but they are translated into a state machine implemented in C (and output as source code).

Comment: @Vladimir Is it important to match the numbers only after `instruction`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yeah, I don't need commas. Actually this answer which was posted looks to solve the problem, don't you guys agree? https://regex101.com/r/svPWt9/2

Comment: @Vladimir It is a PCRE pattern. Are you using PCRE? All you indicated is that you want to use built-in libraries, right? Please add the regex flavor/library you are using. With PCRE, you can use [`(?:instruction\s|(?!^)\G,)\K\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/svPWt9/4), too, but is it helpful *for you*?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I need it to work in C++, and it looks like that regex I posted doesn't work in C++

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7257415/3832970) that explains what to do.

Comment: IMO closing this question was premature. Especially duplicate doesn't have a good answer, here is [my solution of the problem](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Bgs6YAKv0lee4vyU).

Comment: I've provided an [answer under a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51641925/1387438).